# AngularJS ui-router - different states on different device-widths

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I'm currently developing a Phonegap App, which should work for Android, iPhone and iPad.

The views differ on various sizes (landscape, portrait) etc. So I've got a different view on the iPhone then on the iPad.

To get a better picture just look at the Mail app on the iPhone/iPad. On iPad, you have the list on the left and the content on the right. On iPhone, you've got your list and when you click on an item, you transition to the article/detailed view.

Now I'm trying to achieve this with angular-ui router states.

I want to load a different view, e.g. above a device-width of `700px`, to provide a better user-experience.

Now my question:

How can I tell `$stateProvider` to load a different view, depending on the window width?

Comment: Uh, `if ($(window).width() > 700) $state.go("somewhereElse")`? I don't see where the confusion would be.

Comment: that's not what I wanted. I have to choose which template to load for the different layout. I came up with using ng-include and a dynamic template
`<div ng-include src="templateBasedOnWidth" onload="recalculateContentViewWidth()"></div>`
but is there a better solution?

Comment: Or, just use `templateProvider` to calculate which template you need and return it accordingly.